# the right way to pass structures in C

Tags: c

I'm a beginner in programming and this is my first time here. i need your help in solving this problem..

now, what i want to solve is to write a code that prints out an information and attributes of a football players in a team. here is an example..

[image]

this is Lionel Messi the famous football player.. as you can see at the right corner there is his attributes, every player has 3 categories of attributes.. Technical Attributes, Mental Attributes, and Physical. the maximum rating is 20 for every attribute.

now i coded this in 2 ways, and i don't know which one is the right way, or if both ways are wrong and bad programming..

the first way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
void Messi ();
int main()
{
    Messi();
    return 0;
}

void Messi ()
{ 
    struct player10 
    { 
        char technical[150];
        char mental[150];
        char physical[150]; 
    };

    struct player10 messi;

    strcpy(messi.technical, "Corners: 14\nCrossing: 15\nDribbling: 20\nFinishing: 20\nFirst Touch: 20\nFree Kick: 15\nHeading: 12\nLong shots: 17\nPassing: 19\nPenalty Taking: 18\nTechnique: 20\n");

    strcpy(messi.mental, "Agression: 7\nAnticipation: 19\nBravery: 7\nComposure: 19\nConsentration: 14\nDecisions: 19\nDetermination: 20\nFlair: 20\nLeadership: 14\nOff The Ball:      18\nTeamWork: 13\nVision: 20\nWork Rate: 7\n");

    printf("Messi Technical:\n%s \t Messi    Mental:\n%s",messi.technical,messi.mental);

    return;
}
```

the second way:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct player10
{
    char technical[150];
    char mental[150];
    char physical[150];
};


int main()
{
    struct player10 messi;
    printf("Messi Attributes: \n");         
    Messi_attr(messi);
    return 0;
}


int Messi_attr (struct player10 messi)
{
    strcpy(messi.technical,"Corners: 14\nCrossing: 15\nDribbling: 20\nFinishing: 20\nFirst Touch: 20\nFree Kick: 15\nHeading: 12\nLong shots: 17\nPassing: 19\nPenalty Taking: 18\nTechnique: 20\n");

    printf("\nTechnical Attributes:\n\n%s", messi.technical);

    strcpy(messi.mental,"Agression: 7\nAnticipation: 19\nBravery: 7\nComposure: 19\nConsentration: 14\nDecisions: 19\nDetermination: 20\nFlair: 20\nLeadership: 14\nOff The Ball: 18\nTeamWork: 13\nVision: 20\nWork Rate: 7\n");

    printf("\nMental Attributes:\n\n%s", messi.mental);

    strcpy(messi.physical,"Acceleration: 18\nAgility: 20\nBalance: 17\nJumping Reach: 6\nNatural Fitness: 14\nPace: 15\nStamina: 13\nStrength: 8\n");

    printf("\nPhysical Attributes:\n\n%s", messi.physical); 

    return 0;
}
```

am i doing it right? or there is an easier way to code this with passing structures?
any help would be appreciated..

Comment: Well as it is now, the easiest way to code it is `printf("\nTechnical Attributes:\n\nCorners: 14\nCrossing: 15\n`... and so on.

Comment: #1 makes no sense at all. #2 is better but still wrong.

Comment: Write a function to create a player10 struct and one to print it. Mixing them up makes no sense. Also using the struct as a type might help. `typedef struct {...} player10;` in a haeder file or at the begin of the code would be nice.

Comment: Pass structures by reference (i.e. pointer) unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: No offence, but you really should start with something simpler. Your code shows missconceptions about how functions work, what to return and how data is passed in C. Reading a good C book would be a start.

Comment: @paddy: C does not support pass-by-reference. A pointer is a first-class type and also passed by value.

Comment: @immibis thank you for your respond.. it seems that you didn't understand my question and its my bad.. i know that the easiest way to code it is by the method you've mentioned.. but i was asking about how to code this by passing structures method

Comment: @Olaf: i guess you mean the way number 2 by saying my code shows misconceptions about how functions work.. i thought this was simple enough..

Comment: Since Diego Maradona will have the same list of attributes (unless you add a `Hand of God` attribute, rated 20, presumably), your data representation is not really appropriate.  It will be hard to establish which player in a squad of 20 players has the highest score for Positioning, for example.  You need to think about how to restructure the data.

Comment: @whiteknights: That's not the only issue. It is not clear what you wanbt to accomplish. Before starting to code, you first should understand the problem. Then think how you can structure your code and how to design the interfaces.

Comment: you would be much better off in a different language. Can you use c#, Python, etc. ? Even c++ would be better than raw C. You will drown in dynamically managed arrays of structures with lists etc once you get your data structures correct

Comment: @Olaf: i was studying how to pass structures and structures pointers, so i just wanted to do an exercise and my mind came up with this..

Comment: @Olaf: i want to start with low level languages first because i want to have a better understanding of how things works.. so i was planing of Assembly after C, then C++.. and then high level languages comes afterwards.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: thank you.. i will try to think of a way to restructure the data.. and i agree, Diego Maradona have a similar list of attributes, and maybe even slightly better mentally.. but i think Messi is the god of our age.

Comment: @whiteknights: How does that contradict my comment? C is not a low-level language, it does not provide higher degrees of abstractions, but that does not make it a low-level language. And the lower abstraction available the more planning is necessary. But the point is you first should learn the basics before you start a more advanced project.

Comment: @Olaf: thank you.. i wasn't referring to C as a low level language, i meant languages like Python. and because C isn't a low-level language i felt that i should've started with a lower level one. i don't know, but it feels right to me starting from the root, knowing how stuff works from scratch, even if its going to be harder to study & understand. but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @whiteknights: Starting with the basics is fine and exactly what I recommended. As your question is about C, that means exactly you should first learn the basics of the language. Reading a book (and later the standard itself) will help getting the whole picture, video-tutorials will not. They even often fail for simple things; you will not find many true C experts and those mostly have no time/interest to make video-tutorials.

Comment: @Olaf: thank you.. so do you recommend i relay only on books? as you know there is no many sources at the internet  except video tutorials and books. so I'm kinda have no choice.

Comment: @whiteknights: I did not say you should rely on booky **only** (nor that you should rel**a**y on them;-). I wonder how we learned programming when there was no youtube, no web, not even Internet. That's indeed a miracle. And yet we knew very well what we did and why ...

Comment: @Olaf: there was a school or college back then.. i guess its more helpful than self-study.

Comment: @whiteknights: Not really. Most engineers did not learn programming at shool, nor university or college. Self-studies seemd to have worked quite well back then; maybe people were used to learn for themselves and not to be spoon-fed?

Comment: @Olaf: i guess you're right, back then there was much space of time for people, but now everything is running fast and people want a short cut way.

Comment: ... at the cost of people who learned it properly. Sorry, but your statement is just a lame excuse for being lazy and getting spoon-fed. Programming is like maths: you have to understand; memorizing patterns does not help.

Comment: @Olaf: i think you misunderstood me, my statement was just me agreeing with you that most people these days wants to learn everything quickly and get spoon-fed. back then people managed there time properly and worked harder.

Comment: @whiteknights: Ok, sorry, I took your statement as mean seriously. For the record: I'm fine with quick learning. Just not at the cost of others. And some things (and people) just take their time to learn. You just can't become a master software developer after 1 year.

Comment: @Olaf: I'm taking my time, maybe overly so. i just study 3 days a week each day for around 2 hours or something. to be honest i don't really have a goal, I'm not too excited to have a job or to become a software developer.. I'm just curious about this stuff and how computer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `player10` structure **by pointer** into a function to be populated with the required strings. In c it's a reasonably common pattern to have the passed in object as optional, so it does not force the program to use the heap. If you pass NULL then it allocates what it returns and as a result you need to free the result.

You can create a set of functions prefixed with `player_` (or `player10_` if you want I didn't get the significance of `10`), which operate on player and encapsulate it somewhat. Below I show `player_create` which is effectively the constructor and `player_print` to print all the player.

Example here hopefully helps you somewhat. I also show how it could be used with no existing player `struct`.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define FIELD_SIZE  150

typedef struct 
{
    char technical[FIELD_SIZE];
    char mental[FIELD_SIZE];
    char physical[FIELD_SIZE];
} player10;

char* sstrncpy(char* dest, char* src, size_t destsize){

    dest[destsize - 1] = '\0';
    return strncpy(dest, src, destsize - 1);
}

player10* player_create(player10* p, char* tech, char* mental, char* physical)
{
    if(!p){
        p = malloc(sizeof(player10));
        assert(p);
    }

    sstrncpy(p->technical, tech, FIELD_SIZE);
    sstrncpy(p->mental, mental, FIELD_SIZE);
    sstrncpy(p->physical, physical, FIELD_SIZE);

    return p;
}

void player_print(player10* p)
{
    printf("technical: %s\n", p->technical);
    printf("mental: %s\n", p->mental);
    printf("physical: %s\n", p->physical);
}

int main()
{
    player10 messi;

    // some like to reset their structs
    //memset(&messi, 0, sizeof(player10));

    player_create(&messi,
        "Corners: 14\nCrossing: 15\nDribbling: 20\nFinishing: 20\nFirst Touch: 20\nFree Kick: 15\nHeading: 12\nLong shots: 17\nPassing: 19\nPenalty Taking: 18\nTechnique: 20\n",
        "Agression: 7\nAnticipation: 19\nBravery: 7\nComposure: 19\nConsentration: 14\nDecisions: 19\nDetermination: 20\nFlair: 20\nLeadership: 14\nOff The Ball: 18\nTeamWork: 13\nVision: 20\nWork Rate: 7\n",
        "Acceleration: 18\nAgility: 20\nBalance: 17\nJumping Reach: 6\nNatural Fitness: 14\nPace: 15\nStamina: 13\nStrength: 8\n");

    printf("Messi Attributes: \n");
    player_print(&messi);

    player10* ronaldo = player_create(NULL, "stuff", "stuff", "stuff");

    printf("Ronaldo Attributes: \n");
    player_print(ronaldo);
    free(ronaldo);

    return 0;
}
```

If you plan to operate on these `player10` structures much though, I'd recommend storing your parameters differently. You should perhaps have substructures `technical`, `mental` & `physical` which contain numeric fields. That way your data is far more query able, will occupy less space and you can avoid issue with the sizes of your string buffers and copying strings etc.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. that was helpful, and will be helpful more when i finish studying all the chapters, i haven't study malloc lesson yet and terminologies like 'typedef' ,'dest','src','sizeof' 'assert','\0'. are not familiar to me yet. so maybe after more studying i will have a better understanding of your code. as for 'struct player10', 10 is just the number of the player.. like 'player10 messi', 'player9 ronaldo' etc..

Comment: You're welcome. I can take the malloc bit out if you want? src and dest are just variable names, nothing language specific. I had to do that to ensure the string copy was safe. Answers come under a lot of scrutiny on here.

Comment: I'm going to study malloc tomorrow, maybe after studying it i'll get to understand more. do you think I'm confusing myself with solving problems like this? and i should first finish all the lessons?. because every lesson i study my mind just comes up with examples of complicated exercises like this. i just invent the problem in my mind and try to solve it.

Comment: Any practice is good practice. Just look up the concepts you don't understand or attempt to remove them until you have covered them. Also don't forget to accept the answer if was what you wanted or else let me know how it can be improved.